# Java version shows 7 and Java version shows 8 in windows?

Tags: java-8, java-7

I am really frustrated to see following behavior and not sure yet after research how to fixed this. I've two separate projects one works only on Java 7 (can't update to Java 8) and another project works on Java 8 (can't downgrade to 7). So I've both Java 7 and 8 installed on my windows machine.

So, I am seeing following behavior constantly. Currently I am on Java 8 and would like switch back Java 7, so I changed environment variable JAVA_HOME and PATH to point to Java 7, but when I verify through CMD, it shows me following.

```
C:\>java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

C:\>javac -version
javac 1.7.0_71
```

I can't use above combination, neither projects works for me. So I always need to uninstalled Java 8 and then only I can point to Java 7. 
Also if I want to move back to Java 8 (again installed Java 8), then it shows me following combination. **How to fixed this error on Windows?** As uninstalling the JDK every time is not the solution. **Please help me.**

```
C:\>java -version
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

C:\>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_45
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`java.exe`, the Java runtime, also installs in `c:\windows` or `c:\windows\system32` (can't remember, I'm on a Mac now).

So even if your PATH contains the bin directory of JDK, if c:\windows (or c:\windows\system32) comes *before* JDK\bin in the PATH, the version in c:\windows (or c:\windows\system32) is the one that is used.

Just make sure the JDK is first in the PATH, or at least before c:\windows (or c:\windows\system32).

Comment: Have you restarted cmd.exe after making this change? Because that's not taken into account in existing cmd.exe instances. Also, what  is C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath?

Comment: Lately I've seen links in `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` and that dir added to path.  I can no longer find java.exe in any windows dir.  Also it's 64 bit so I don't think it would be in sys32.

Comment: JBNizet provided the right answer. @User4567570:  Setting `JAVA_HOME` env. variable to the path of the JDK (e.g. c:\java\jdk8u60\)  to use is the only things to update, if the `PATH` env. variable itself is set with `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`, and if its position is located before the declaration of system32. The console need to be restarted for the environment variables to take effect. The discrepency between `javac -version` and `java -version` means that both location are defined, for each JDK, in the path.